# Why does reversing the string in Python via slicing works this way?

Tags: python, slice

I am trying to write my own version of the reversed() function and I don't quite understand how the suggested solution works.

```
a="sample string"
# my solution
reversed_a=a[len(a):-1:-1] 

#suggested solution
reversed_a=[::-1]
```

Shouldn't `[::]` mean `[0:len(a)]`? If so, how does it work then? I though it would go from 0 to `len(a)` with a step of -1 and raise an exception due to the negative index value.

Comment: General observation. If you mention *suggested solution*, you should indicate where it was suggested.

Comment: @DeepSpace Unfortunately, the duplicate does not **explain** why begin and end of the list are changed when using negative strides, just mentions it.

Comment: @SergeyA [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24713353/789671) (for example) goes into a bit more detail.

Comment: @glibdud thanks for the link. It's a pity it is not reflected in official documentation (at least, I was not able to find it).

Comment: @SergeyA It behaves exactly like `range` does (`range(end, start, negative_step)`)

Comment: @DeepSpace I do not immediately see where it explains how negative step forces reverse iteration with default arguments.

Comment: @glibdud You are actually right, the second answer does go more into the details of this behavior(when one or more of the indexes is `None`) . @SergeyA it is written in the part, where the full notation (`my_list[-9:None:None]`) is talked about. Just after the **Explanation** header